# How to use revalidatePath on Nextjs13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm studying nextJs13, I didn't understand how revalidatePath works.

I don't understand how can I use revalidatePath, is a function ? Or is a GET endpoint ?

I have two differnt page,  when I try to modify the first page I need that this modify will be visible on the second page. But when I change page, I can see the modify.

I tryed too  with no-cache  but I can't . Anybody could help me ?

```
  const editProfileUser = async (payload) => {

try {
  const editProfileUser = await putAutheticatedAPI({
    payload,
    endpoint: SETTINGS_PROFILE_USER,
    token: session.user.access_token,
  })
  


  revalidatePath('user/profile')

  return editProfileUser
} catch (e) {
  setError(true)
}
```

}

I get this error :

```
static generation store missing in revalidateTag user/profile
```

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidatePath

Comment: Well first of all most people don't even care to google/check the docs. And second, the docs say pretty much all you need. You just want someone to give you a solution so you don't have to do any more work. Just read the docs and google some more and when you exhausted all your options you can create a post detailing what you did and what did not work and then you can ask for help.

Comment: Go back to Nextjs 12 if it's not too late. Nextjs 13 is a huge failure in almost every way.